# I am trying to install Ubuntu on my phone and ubuntu-device-flash cannot seem to find this url

Tags: ubuntu-touch

This is what happened:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu

Get https://system-image.ubuntu.com/channels.json: dial tcp: lookup system-image.ubuntu.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host"
```

I had to write Ubuntu 16.04 to a flash drive an boot off of it because this package is not available for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Touch is no longer maintained or hosted by Canonical. You need to follow the instructions on https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io to install for your device.

If your device is supported, you can still use `ubuntu-device-flash` but you must pass the server argument as well as correct channel:

`ubuntu-device-flash --server https://system-image.ubports.com touch --channel ubports-touch/16.04/stable`

The old servers and channels will not work any more.